# NodeJS Session & Passport.session() Not Save A Session On Live Server

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

The Problem is shows up on the paid server or when I change the server default domain to my domain.
That's My Code:

> ```
> app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
>         useDefaults: true,
>         defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
>     directives: directives,
>     scriptSrc: scriptSources,
>     scriptSrcElem: scriptSources,
>     styleSrc: styleSources,
>     contentTypes: contentTypes,
>     connectSrc: connectSources,
>     reportUri: "/report-violation",
>     reportOnly: false,
>     safari5: false,
> }));
> app.use(noCache());
> app.use(helmet.noSniff());
> app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
> app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy({ policy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin' }));
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: 
> true }));
> app.use(express.json());
> app.use(device.capture({ parseUserAgent: true 
> }));
> app.disable('x-powered-by');
> app.use(helmet.frameguard());
> app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
> app.use(helmet.hsts({
> maxAge: 3600000,
> includeSubDomains: true,
> force: true,
> }));
> app.use(cookieParser());
> app.use(
> session({
>     name: uuidv4(),
>     secret: process.env.SERET,
>     resave: true,
>     cookie: {
>         sameSite: true,
>         secure: true,
>             maxAge: 3600000,
>         },
>         saveUninitialized: false,
>         store: MongoStore.create({
>             mongoUrl: process.env.dburl, 
> //MONGODB URL
>             ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
>             autoRemove: 'native'
>         }),
>
>     })
> );
> app.use(compression());
> app.use(passport.initialize());
> app.use(passport.session());
> app.use(flash());
> ```

When I Click Login It's Redirect My To Login Page But Without Any Session.
Note: It's Working So Fine On Localhost!.

Please Help.

Best Regards,
Raqeeb Al-Nakib

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by changing the session config as follow:

```
app.use(session({
    name: uuidv4(),
    secret: process.env.SERET,
    resave: false,
    proxy: true, // Set This To True
    cookie: {
        sameSite: true,
        secure:true,  // Set this to True
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 3600000,
    },
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.dburl, //MONGODB URL
        ttl: 24 * 60 * 60,
        autoRemove: 'native'
    }),
})
```